# IE9 / CSS / background color / padding issue

Tags: css, firefox, internet-explorer-9, background-color

I have an issue with IE9 and css. It looks like IE9 doesn't accept the padding definition of the two elements p and a. The background color shrinked and is only in the upper left corner of the elements. The following css works fine in firefox though:

```
<div class="slider">                        
    <p class="claim orange">Some Text</p>
    <a class="claim blue" href="">Some Link</a>         
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.slider p {
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
    z-index: 8000;
    padding: 0.5% 2%;
    line-height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.claim {
    line-height: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
}   

.orange { background: #EF7D00 }

.blue {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 15px; 
    border-color: white;
}

.blue:hover {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 15px; 
    background: #2e6da4;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
    text-decoration: none;
}

</style>
```

What might be the issue and how can I get the background color work in IE9 in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as-is doesn't seem to display a working page, at least for me in Chrome or Firefox.  The p element containing "some text" is displaying with top: -200px, off the page to the top, and the background is white so I can't see anything until I mouseover the link.

Did you forget to include some key lines in your code?  Try pasting everything into a text file and testing it out, before uploading it in a question, or it's going to be hard for us to help you.

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do here!

Comment: Thanks for looking into it cazort. I should have mentioned its in combination with FractionSlider (http://jacksbox.de/stuff/jquery-fractionslider/). And I'm using the js and css from the latest download, in combination with the above lines. The background of the slider is a picture, that's why the color of the elements are white. Hovering over the link just gives me an additional background color. The background of the p's are fix. Everything is working fine in firefox, but in IE9 the whole (except for a small piece in the upper left corner) background color of those elements are gone.*cry